# How to connect to SICK TIM LiDAR through docker?

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to connect to my SICK TIM LiDAR fine when running it from my machine. Here's the basic launch file:

```
<launch>

    <node name="sick_tim310_1" pkg="sick_tim" type="sick_tim310" respawn="false" output="screen">
    </node>

</launch>
```

However, when I try to containerise this with Docker it does not connect to the LiDAR via USB and I get the message:

```
process[sick_tim310_1-2]: started with pid [64]
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310: error while loading shared libraries: libdiagnostic_updater.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[sick_tim310_1-2] process has died [pid 64, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310 __name:=sick_tim310_1 __log:=/root/.ros/log/bc9ceac0-3e11-11eb-a6cb-50eb712545a4/sick_tim310_1-2.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/bc9ceac0-3e11-11eb-a6cb-50eb712545a4/sick_tim310_1-2*.log
```

Here's the minimal Docker file:

```
FROM osrf/ros:noetic-desktop-full

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y nano && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y sudo git && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y usbutils && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y python3-wstool python3-rosdep ninja-build stow && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y ros-noetic-position-controllers && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y ros-noetic-effort-controllers && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y ros-noetic-joint-state-controller && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y ros-noetic-rosbridge-server && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y ros-noetic-sick-tim && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y python3-pip

RUN bash -c "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash && \
             cd ~ && \
             mkdir -p /catkin_ws/src && \
             cd /catkin_ws/src && \
             catkin_init_workspace && \
             mkdir my_package"

COPY . /catkin_ws/src/my_package
WORKDIR ~

RUN bash -c "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash && \
             cd /catkin_ws/ && \
             catkin_make"

RUN bash -c "chmod +x /catkin_ws/src/my_package/container_entrypoint.sh"

RUN bash -c "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash && \
                       source /catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash && \
                       cd && \
                       sudo rm /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list && \
                       cd /catkin_ws && \
                       rosdep init && \
                       rosdep update && \
                       rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=noetic -y"

ENTRYPOINT ["/catkin_ws/src/my_package/container_entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["bash"]
```

The container_entrypoint.sh script referenced is:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
source /catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

exec "$@"
```

The container is run with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -it \
    --rm \
    --privileged \
    --net=host \
    my_package:latest \
    /bin/bash -c \
    "
     roslaunch my_package my_package.launch
    "
export containerId=$(docker ps -l -q)
```

Could anyone point out what I might be doing wrong please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367698/how-to-connect-to-sick-tim-lidar-through-docker?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2020-12-15**:
Is this library installed?

```
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310: error while loading shared libraries: libdiagnostic_updater.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_updater

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-12-15**:
I thought this was but it turned out it was missing! This solved the problem. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested in the first comment, `diagnostic_updater` was missing so installing this fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2020-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2020-12-15**:
You'll want to mark this as the answer to note that the question was resolved.